# Find $1+a^{1}+a^{2}+\ldots +a^{39}$, where $a^{40}+6a=7$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a$ be a negative real number such that $a^{40}+6a=7$. Find $1+a^{1}+a^{2}+\ldots +a^{39}$.

Comment: $a^{40}=1$ and $a<0$ so $a=\ldots$

Comment: Why not write $a^{40}=1$?

Comment: I sorry I forgot 'a' after 6 in $a^{40}+6a=7$

Answer (score 8):

Note that $$1+a+a^2 + \cdots + a^{39} = \dfrac{a^{40}-1}{a-1}$$ Since $a<0$, we have $a-1 \neq 0$. Hence, $\ldots$

Comment: Sorry I forgot 'a' after 6 in $a^{40}+6a=7$

Comment: @user109004 Doesn't matter. You are given that $a^{40} + 6a = 7$. This implies $$a^{40} = 7-6a \implies \dfrac{a^{40}-1}{a-1} = \dfrac{7-6a-1}{a-1} = -6$$